# How can I use puppeteer/selenium to reuse the saved credentials/password when signing in a web site?

Tags: selenium, authentication, puppeteer, credentials, autofill

As we know, we can't make chrome/firefox to autofill the password in the login form, but we can click the username/password pair in the "manage passwords" dialog so that the application doesn't need to input the password again.

The problem is: when we use puppeteer or selenium, we can't access the "manage passwords" dialog to fill in the password for us. 
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: I've never thought that this approach was a great idea because your tests are forced to rely on browser-dependent settings such as managed passwords, which goes against best automation practice of independent tests. If you ever want to run your tests on some kind of a build server, this will cause more maintenance problems down the line. Is there a reason you do not want to type in username/password text?

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to save/restore cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brave browser executable that is based on chromumim and import passwords you have exported from chrome, and you run it like

```js
const chromeExecPath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
const chromeUserDataDir = '/Users/XXX/Library/ApplicationSupport/Google/Chrome/Profile 2'


const braveExecPath = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
const braveUserDataDir = '/Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Profile 1'



const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  puppeteer.launch({headless: false,
    args:['-enable-save-password-bubble'],
    executablePath: braveExecPath,
    userDataDir: braveUserDataDir}).then(async browser => {
```

Comment: I don't think this works. Are you sure puppeteer can read that data dir? I wasn't able to import the autofill passwords that I've saved in brave into puppeteer/chromium. And when I ran the brave executable it was just as if I had reinstalled brave and none of my info was in it.